# how to use LIKE with column name

Tags: sql, mysql

Normally `LIKE` statement is used to check the pattern like data.

example:

```
select * from table1 where name like 'ar%'
```

My problem is to use one column of table with `LIKE` statement.

example:

```
select * from table1, table2 where table1.x is like table2.y%
```

Query above results error . how to use one column data in `like` query?

Comment: From a comment made by Arun, this is for MySQL...

Comment: Give him a break, it's only been 40 minutes since he asked! :)

Comment: B'day Nora!  11 Questions and no accepts?  Cheeky Sod!

Answer (score 99, accepted):

You're close.

The LIKE operator works with strings (CHAR, NVARCHAR, etc).  so you need to concattenate the '%' symbol to the string...

MS SQL Server:

```
SELECT * FROM table1,table2 WHERE table1.x LIKE table2.y + '%'
```

Use of LIKE, however, is often slower than other operations.  It's useful, powerful, flexible, but has performance considerations.  I'll leave those for another topic though :)

EDIT:

I don't use MySQL, but this may work...

```
SELECT * FROM table1,table2 WHERE table1.x LIKE CONCAT(table2.y, '%')
```

Comment: i have error as follows
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '+ %' at line 1

Comment: MySQL doesn't use + as a concatenation operator.  Apparently it's a function called concat() with different functions existing for different data types...

Comment: Apreciate you started your answer with "you're close" unlike most arrogant people here who like to discourage pple. tx

Comment: @MatBailie is this possible with PostgreSQL in any way at all - the above syntax does not work apparently.

Answer (score 33):

SQL SERVER

```
 WHERE ColumnName LIKE '%'+ColumnName+'%'
```

Comment: Thank you for also answering this in SQL SERVER.  Despite @caitriona's comments, people are actually using other DB's out there and may have found this post by using Google

Answer (score 9):

**ORACLE DATABASE example:**

```
select * 
from table1 t1, table2 t2
WHERE t1.a like ('%' || t2.b || '%')
```

Answer (score 7):

```
...
WHERE table1.x LIKE table2.y + '%'
```

Comment: Maybe you need brackets? WHERE table1.x LIKE (table2.y + '%')  -- or maybe "||" instead of "+" as per the SQL standard.

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work. By reading your answer I realized that the `table2.y + '%'` part had to be on the right side of the `LIKE`.

Answer (score 4):

```
declare @LkeVal as Varchar(100)
declare @LkeSelect Varchar(100)

Set @LkeSelect = (select top 1 <column> from <table> where <column> = 'value')
Set @LkeVal = '%' + @LkeSelect

select * from <table2> where <column2> like(''+@LkeVal+'');
```

Comment: This should optimize the query by narrowing the search from the first table.

Answer (score 0):

For SQLLite you will need to concat the strings

```sql
select * from list1 l, list2 ll 
WHERE l.name like "%"||ll.alias||"%";
```

Answer (score 0):

for MySql you use like below,which is worked for me

```
SELECT * FROM table1, table2 WHERE table1.x LIKE (table2.y);
```

It takes table2's column values of y.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
SELECT * FROM `mdl_user` WHERE `firstname` LIKE concat(lastname,'%') AND lastname != ''
```