# how to use LIKE with column name with SQLite

Tags: sqlite, sql-like

I have a SQLite table with columns like these: `id, name_1, name_2, name_nick, phone, email`

and I am looking for a way to search in all columns which begins with `name_`.

Like LIKE but for the column names.

I find a lot for MySQL etc, but just this one for SQLite:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/60814644/8110291
But it is for a query with two tables and i need only one.

The solution should be pure SQL, because I am just starting to deal with this language and I want to get to know the possibilities.

Comment: If it's only searching three columns, why not just use OR?

Comment: No, there are mor columns, 'name_' was just an example.